# There are no housenumbers om OSM map

Tags: openstreetmap, tile, mapnik

I successfully installed tile server based on the instruction given in the switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/. So I have well-working web-server + tile-server. But there are no housenumbers on map. I add my next code in my imposm-mapping.py

```
buildings = Polygons (
    name = 'buildings',
    fields = (
        ('area', PseudoArea()),
        ('addr:housenumber', String()),
    ),
    mapping = {
        'building': (
            '__any__',
        ),
        'railway': (
            'station',
        )
        'aeroway': (
            'terminal',
        ),
    }
)
```

In my labels.mss I have:

```
#housenumber [zoom>=17]{
    ::label {
    text-name: '[addr:housenumber]';
    text-face-name:@sans;
    text-size: 9;
    text-placement: interior;
    text-min-dostance: 1;
    text-wrap-width: 0;
    text-fill: #444;
    }
}
```

In default.style I have `node,way addr:housenumber text linear`.
I saw question [Map won't show building numbers (tileMill + OSM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685006/map-wont-show-building-numbers-tilemill-osm/20688689#20688689). But I don't understand this tips.

Comment: Your labels.mss contains `addr:housenumbers` but the correct key is `addr:housenumber` (without the trailing s). Could this be the problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, it is just mistake in my question. There is every thing right in code. May be I must add code like this `( SELECT way, "addr:housenumber" 
  FROM planet_osm_polygon
  WHERE  "addr:housenumber"  IS NOT NULL
) AS data` to somewhere. But I don't know where. Can't find some tips or examples about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem solved. I just reload data to database with carto.style, rebuild tile server with swich2osm instructions but with stylesheet from openstreetmap-carto. Not OSMBright