# How to show building numbers on Apple Map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-maps

can we show building numbers on apple map? if yes then how can we achieve this? please refer the screenshot.[image]

Comment: I think you need custom tiles overlay

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not update Apple map but yes for alter-net solution you can use google map for showing you floor plan on map.

By using "Map Objects" feature of google map you can  add your custom floor plan on provided location.

**Check this link of Map object in Google map:** [Map Objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map)

There is one more solution for your requirement.

Use `SVG` file and annotate your building number on it.

**for `SVG` map update check this link:** [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/)

**One more useful link from SO:** [Map won't show building numbers (tileMill + OSM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685006/map-wont-show-building-numbers-tilemill-osm)

Hope above information will help you to go further in your R&D for building number placed on map.